# VB.NET & Linq: Sum datatable column and Group by date in another column

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a typedDataset (ds) and its datatable(dt). The datatable has the columns `Date`(ttmmyyy) and `Worktime`. I want to sum the Worktime by month. I already accomplished to sum the Worktime with

```
Dim sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum((Function(x) x.Worktime))
```

I need help with group this by month.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a table with your fields and the following query worked nice:

```
 Dim query = From row In dt
          Group row By VarDate= row.Field(Of DateTime)("Date") Into MonthGroup = Group
          Select New With {
              Key VarDate,
              .Worktime = MonthGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("Worktime"))
         }
```

Used variable `VarDate` because Date is reserved for it's own class.

**Output:**

> Vardate: 10/15/2013 Worktime: 150
>
> Vardate: 10/16/2013 Worktime: 180

EDIT:

To get the output just use:

```
 For Each obj In query
     Dim datet = obj.VarDate
     Dim WorkH = obj.Worktime
 Next
```

To avoid declarying types when using linq, insert the line: `option infer on` on the very first line of the vb.net document ( so you can use dim datet = obj.Vardate ) without declaring the type. It is like var in c#

Comment: Hi! first off thank you for replying! How did you get the output? I tried: For Each sumq In query MsgBox("You worked" & sumq.Worktime.ToString & "in Month" & sumq.VarDate.ToString) Next but the result i get is for each day not grouped by month. P.S.: I changed Int32 with decimal but i think this is not the reason for the different output.

Comment: Hi! Iterating throu query (code you added) gives me hours for every day not grouped by month. To display that, i inserted msgbox(datet.tostring & " " & WorkH.tostring) in the for each enviroment.